# How do you install a new debug-apk without manually uninstalling the old debug-apk with a mismatching signature?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-install-apk

I have a hardware product with an application that the user is not able to exit. When there is a new update, the user is able to update to the newest version within the app. We release debug-apk's, not the signed ones.

I read that Android studio automatically signs debug-apk's. I have a new version of the app that I want to release, but the old apk's signature doesn't match the new apk signature. The users are not able to uninstall the app and reinstall the new one since they can not leave the app. I am not able to go around the world manually updating everyones product.

Question: What would be the best way to uninstall the old apk and install the new one without the user having to manually uninstall and install the new apk.

Suggestions: Is there a way to find out the old apk's automatically generated signature and change the new one to match it? Or is there a way to create a service that can uninstall the old apk and install the new one?

Comment: http://www.hugestreet.info/install-unsigned-apk-on-android-device/

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132374/how-do-i-force-reinstallation-of-an-apk-with-different-signature-on-rooted-andro

Comment: Try these solutions please if you have root access

Comment: "Is there a way to find out the old apk's automatically generated signature and change the new one to match it?" -- no. "Or is there a way to create a service that can uninstall the old apk and install the new one?" -- you could create a third app that does this. However, it's unclear how any of your upgrades are working, as updates (and uninstalls) require user intervention, in the form of agreeing to those operations via system-supplied activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could just copy the debug.keystore file from the original computer where the older versions of the app were made and replace my debug.keystore file in the users\yourname.android location on my computer. Then I had to restart android studio and everything worked normally again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use that `debug-key` for signing your new APK and release it. 
And your user can update to new one.

Actually, you don't sign the new app and just build an APK with debug-key and release it.

with below code in your gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
     debug {
         storeFile file("debug.keystore")
     }
 }
```